# How to change PerfMon graph legend in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

The perfMon output graph has IP of the server being monitored in the legend. Is there an option to change this to a meaningful name (like DBServer_Dev, WebServer_Dev) so the legend is more readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perfmon output graph displays either IP or [DNS hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) of the machine you configure in the [PerfMon Metrics Collector](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)

If DNS hostnames are not informative enough you can i.e. use [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) and create your custom bindings between "meaningful names" and IP addresses

[image]

More information just in case: [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)